# Где в приложении на React хранить флаг авторизирован ли пользователь или нет

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Имеется компонент:

```
import React from 'react';
import {  Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = React.lazy(() => import('./Components/Header/Header'));
const RegistrationForm = React.lazy(() => import('./Components/Forms/RegistrationForm/RegistrationForm'));
const LogonForm = React.lazy(() => import('./Components/Forms/LogonForm/LogonForm'));

import ContentLayout from './Layouts/ContentLayout/ContentLayout';
import DepartmentForm from './Components/Forms/DepartmentForm/DepartmentInput';

import './App.css';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loggedIn: false
        };

        this.logIn = this.logIn.bind(this);
    }

    logIn() {
        this.setState({
            loggedIn: true
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Header />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" render={ () => (this.state.loggedIn ? (<DepartmentForm/>) : (<Redirect to="/login"/>))}/>
                        <Route exact path="/login" render={ () =>  <LogonForm logIn={ this.logIn } />  } />
                        <Route exact path="/registration" render={ (props) => <RegistrationForm {...props} /> } />
                    </Switch>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
};
```

Флаг авторизации я храню в state. Насколько это правильно? И как сделать чтоб при обновлении страницы это состояние не сбрасывалось?

Answer (score 0):

Храните признак того, что пользователь авторизован в `localStorage`, таким образом при перезагрузке страницы это состояние не будет сбрасываться.

Свойство `localStorage` позволяет получить доступ к локальному `Storage` объекту.  Данные в свойстве `localStorage` не имеют ограничений по времени хранения и могут быть удалены только с помощью JavaScript, то есть не имеют определенного времени жизни.

Пример использования:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    loggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem('loggedIn'),
  };
}

logIn() {
  this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
  localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', 'yes');
}

logOut() {
  this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
  localStorage.removeItem('loggedIn');
}
```

Вот такой простой пример использования `localStorage` в качестве хранилища. Полезные ссылки для ознакомления и изучения:

- [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage) - интерфейс Storage из Web Storage API
- [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) - хранилище localStorage
- [Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) - хранилище sessionStorage
- [Storage.getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) - вернет значение, лежащее в хранилище по указанному ключу
- [Storage.setItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) - добавит этот ключ в Storage или обновит его значение
- [Storage.removeItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem) - удалит из Storage элемент с указанным ключем
- [Storage.key()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/key) - числовое значение n и возвращает имя nо ключа из Storage
- [Storage.clear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/clear) - удалить все ключи из Storage
- [Storage.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/length) - количество элементов в объекте Storage

Comment: Спасибо. Как мне выполнить ф-ю logIn в компоненте <LogonForm logIn={ this.logIn } /> Не назначая ее на событие?

Comment: @play0rdie вы же передаете функцию `this.logIn` через пропсу `logIn`, вот и вызовите через `this.props.logIn()` функцию внутри компонента `LogonForm`, после того, как выполните необходимые действия.Всё просто должно быть.

Comment: я так и делаю, но дело в том что мне эту ф-я надо повесить не на событие в компоненте, а выполнить внутри метода компонента LogonForm. Я делаю это так как выговорите, но состояние не меняется.

Comment: @play0rdie значит Вы что-то делаете не так 

Comment: [ссылка на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/951051/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-react) может поможете решить проблему